Is it wrong to inject IConfiguration into a model class?
I am returning an instance of this class from an API:
public class MerchantInfo
{
    public int MerchantId { get; set; }
    public string ClickUrl => $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WebsiteDomain")}/{MerchantId}";
}

Appsettings.json:
{
    "WebsiteDomain": "SomeDomain.com"
}

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WebsiteDomain") is returning null, so I'm wondering if I have to inject IConfiguration in the ctor in order to access appsettings.json values?
It feels wrong to be injection IConfiguration into a model class.

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(), you are attempting to get the value from the environment variable, not from appsettings.json

@YongShun Is it possible to add settings in appsettings.json to the env vars?

Just my 2 cents, I don't think it is wrong to use IConfiguration in the model class, it is based on your use case.

The question is not a duplicate of How do I access Configuration in any class in ASP.NET Core?. The title just needs correction to reflect the content of this question, which is whether it is a good practice to inject IConfiguration into model classes.

It's simple, inject the IConfiguration into whatever action \ middleware you are using to return that model, and set model properties directly. For example:
public class MerchantInfo
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    
    public int MerchantId { get; set; }
    public string ClickUrl => $"{Domain}/{MerchantId}";
}

Then in your controller (in case you use MVC):
public ActionResult<MerchantInfo> GetMerchantInfo([FromServices] IConfiguration configuration)
{
    //...
    
    return new MerchantInfo
    {
        Domain = configuration["WebsiteDomain"],
        MerchantId = "<YOUR_ID>"
    };
}

It's true that injecting services to models is not a good idea, since models should not be aware of your application's environment variables or configuration, they only represent data.
If you still don't feel like using IConfiguration, there are other ways like using the options pattern.
